# Displaying ajax data in a graphical representation using high charts

Tags: json, web-services, highcharts

I am trying to display graphs using High charts. I want 12hour format time(hours) in x-axis and y-axis should have min value of 0 and max 5 with a step of 0.5.(i.e.,0,0.5,1.0,1.5...5). The data for the graph should be from webservice that returns Json data. Here one more thing is that I will not use the entire JSON data. Let us suppose if my JSON will be something like this:

```
      [  
            {  
               "Id": 1,  
               "Name": "Tom",  
               "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 2:55:45 AM",  
               "Experience" : "2"
            },
            {  
               "Id": 2,  
               "Name": "Jim",  
               "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 2:05:45 AM",  
               "Experience" : "3"
            } ,
            {  
               "Id": 3,  
               "Name": "Jane",  
               "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 09:05:45 AM",  
               "Experience" : "3"
            }   
           {  
               "Id": 4,  
               "Name": "John",  
               "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 10:05:45 AM",  
               "Experience" : "3"
            },
            {  
               "Id": 5,  
               "Name": "Tim",  
               "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 2:55:45 AM",  
               "Experience" : "4"
            } ,
            {  
               "Id": 6,  
               "Name": "Jerry",  
               "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 2:20:10 AM",  
               "Experience" : "3.5"
            }   
        ]
```

I want to display the date of joining in x-axis and experience in y-axis. X-axis and Y-axis should follow the conditions mentioned above. Now I want some thing like this. If u consider Tom and Jim both have joined on Feb4 only the time is different . So in my X-axis if I have something like 1, 2, 3, 4......12(hrs) Tom and Jim should fall between 2 & 3 I am not knowing how to do this. Can anyone please help me.  If u know any other charts that can suit this requirement please post them also. If you provide sample one...that will be really helpful.
Thanks in advance
Regards
Hema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your dates to timestamps, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/1108/

```
var json = [{
    "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Tom",
        "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 2:55:45 AM",
        "Experience": "2"
}, {
    "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Jim",
        "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 2:05:45 AM",
        "Experience": "3"
}, {
    "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Jane",
        "DOJ": "Feb 4, 2011 09:05:45 AM",
        "Experience": "3"
}],
    data = [],
    jLen = json.length,
    i = 0;


for(; i < jLen; i++){
    var p = json[i];
    data.push({
        name: p.Name,
        y: parseFloat(p.Experience),
        id: p.Id,
        x: (new Date(p.DOJ)).getTime()
    });
}


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'scatter'
    },        
    yAxis: {
        minTickInterval: 0.5    
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'    
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```